# RStudio: My code now runs many times slower than it did before on the same computer

Tags: r, performance, rstudio

I'm looking for an advice please. After cca 6 months I got back to a code I wrote that by then took around 30 minutes to finish. Now, when I run it's way slower. It looks like it could take days. Since back then, hardware didn't change, I'm using Windows 10 and since then I updated my RStudio to current version (2022.07.2 Build 576), and I didn't update R version, which is "4.1.2 (2021-11-01)".

I noticed that in contrast to before, now RStudio is not using more than around 400MB RAM. Before it was much more. I don't run any other SW and there is plenty RAM available.

I had an idea that antivirus might cause this, even though I didn't change any settings. I put RStudio and R to exceptions and didn't change anything.

I also updated RStudio from the previous version, which didn't help.

Please, does anyone have an idea what can be causing this? Sorry if the description is not optimal, it's my first post here and I'm not a programmer, I just use R for data analysis for my biology related diploma thesis.

Thanks a lot!

Daniel

Comment: It seems unlikely that a change of RStudio would affect the speed at which code runs because RStudio doesn't run the code, R itself runs the code. Without any sort of reproducible example it's really impossible to guess why things might be different now. Maybe your data changed or you updated a package. To find out why code takes a while to run, you should [measure performance](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/perf-measure.html) and see what's really taking the most time.

Comment: You might think the code is unchanged from when you ran it in the past, but perhaps you made an accidental change at the time, one which is coming to light now. That is my guess. Based on the information that you provided, nothing more than guesses are possible. Perhaps you could ask how to fix your current code rather than try to figure out exactly what went wrong.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies, I appreciate your help. Unfortunately, I cannot provide the data to make a reproducible example. Anyway, I ran the code on a more powerful computer and I successfully got the results. Still, it took much longer than it used to take. I tried to downgrade the RStudio version, reinstalled R to the same version, reinstalled all packages. But none of that made a difference. I double checked that my input data had no changes since then, nor the script. Anyway, now I don't need the code, so I'm not going to investigate it any further. Thank you once again.